# How to label underneath "buckets" when writing out a combinatorial problem

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

How would I go about creating a set of buckets for a combinatorial problem with labels underneath? What I mean is something like:

$$ _ _ _ _ _ $$

and underneath each "bucket" I have a character such as 1,2,3,4?   How would I do this properly in Latex?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\underbucket[1]{\underset{#1}{\,\underline{\phantom{#1}}\,}}
\begin{document}
\[x=\underbucket{1}\underbucket{2}\underbucket{3}\underbucket{4}\]
\end{document}`?

Comment: who would've thought it is actually called an underbucket......thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very simple(-minded) macro for that purpose.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\underbucket[1]{\underset{#1}{\,\underline{\phantom{#1}}\,}}
\begin{document}
\[x=\underbucket{1}\underbucket{2}\underbucket{3}\underbucket{4}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Whether or not it answers

> How would I do this properly in Latex?

depends on what you mean by "properly",<sup>1</sup> but it is a start.

BTW, it is called `\underbucket` because I called the macro that way. You could call it `\FunkyLittleFurBall` and it would also do its job.

<sub><sup>1</sup>One may want to fiddle around with the spacing between these and so on and so forth.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the very elegant answer, Schrodinger's cat. Modifying your code, one could also do ```\newcommand\underbucket[2]{\underset{#1}{\,\underline{#2}\,}}
``` in order to enable writing stuff above the little dashes, in case OP needs it. (Not trying to steal your answer! I love learning from your codes, so I always try to see if I can use your ideas and tweak them a bit on my own; it's the best way that helps me learn :) )

Comment: @lazulikid That's a good idea! But I'd make it optional: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\underbucket[2][\empty]{\underset{#2}{\,\underline{\ifx#1\empty
\phantom{#2}\else
#1\fi}\,}}
\begin{document}
\[x=\underbucket{1}\underbucket{2}\underbucket{3}\underbucket[a]{4}\]
\end{document}`.